# HTTP redirection without updating document.location

Tags: http, redirect

We have a service located at a url like `services.example.com/123456/*`. We'd like to provide that same service at a url like `www.example.com`. The original service is provided by a PaaS provider which doesn't work with custom domains.

We want a request to go something like this: browser requests `www.example.com/path`, we tell it to go to `services.example.com/123456/path`, and it gets the data from there, but treats the response as if it came from `www.example.com/path` - so doesn't update `document.location` or the url at the top, and treats links as relative to the original path.

Is this possible, or would we have to have a own proxy-like website?

Answer (score 0):

You need a proxy that do url rewriting.